# Where to upload keystore.p12 file for apple push notification on ec2 spring ( javapns)

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am trying to implement apple push notification (dev sandbox) within my spring project, using ( javapns ). I have created all the certificates & private key correctly ( and have checked the same from my local machine). Now when I upload "myck.p12" at the root of my spring project on ec2 instance and then when my code calls Push.alert(msg,"location of .p12 under root","password",token) - the program directly jumps into finally ( without giving any error ).

I also checked connection from my ec2 instance with telnet to apple's sandbox gateway and the connection is also fine.

Any help is appreciated. Could the issue be in locating keystore (.p12 file) ?

Code:

```
import javapns.Push;
import javapns.devices.Device;
import javapns.notification.PushNotificationPayload; 
import javapns.notification.PushedNotification;
import javapns.notification.ResponsePacket;

@Override
public void executePush () throws NetworkIOException {

try {

     List<PushedNotification>  notifications = Push.alert(message,"/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/tapcliqweb/pushtestq.p12","mads",false,"fc382beb521a43859bdc8ce8ed9f636f3b2f20972c712d58f15e15704fe153f7");                 
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
 }
 finally {

        logger.debug("push attempt completed: finally");
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?  Might make it easier to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @ CodeChimp - I have added to code which gives that error. Note: It is a spring web project and I have stored keystore file in root of my web project (i.e., tapcliqweb - as mentioned in the path starting with /env). Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you tried to open the .p12 as a File, do you get an IOException?  Does it open and let you read from it?

Comment: Programmaticaly it doesn't return anything

Comment: I could read it and printed the log it was in unreadable format.

Comment: It is opening up and not giving any IOException but the push notification call after the file read still runs into some issue wherein program directly jumps into finally block

Comment: Right, I was just trying to rule out that the file wasn't being opened at that path.  So, if you can open the same path and read the file, that means the path is good.  I think the next thing would be to download the source and start tracing.

Comment: I converted this code to a jsp and ran it as a simple project on another ec2 instance where it worked but it doesn't with my spring project

Comment: When you say you converted to a JSP, you used scriptlet?

Comment: @CodeChimp - Sorry for a very late response. I found the solution  ( answered below ).  Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was missing required jar file : bcprov-jdk15-146.jar